# Using RVM, but can't set current Ruby version (Ubuntu 11.10)

Tags: ruby, rvm

I have recently installed RVM on a fresh install of Ubuntu 11.10 and can not work out how to start using a particular ruby version.

I have installed Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.2, and they show up in the list fine:

```
$ rvm list
rvm rubies
   ruby-1.8.7-p352 [ i386 ]
   ruby-1.9.2-p290 [ i386 ]
```

When I try to use the "use" command, everything seems fine:

```
$ rvm use 1.9.2
Using /usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290
Running /usr/share/ruby-rvm/hooks/after_use
```

But then when I test the current ruby version, I get the usual Ubuntu 11.10 message you get when you don't have RVM at all:

```
$ ruby -v
The program 'ruby' can be found in the following packages:
 * ruby1.8
 * ruby1.9.1
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

What am I doing wrong? Did I miss out a step in the RVM installation or something?

**EDIT***

Answers to some comments:

```
$ which ruby
#returns nothing at all.

$ which rvm 
/usr/bin/rvm

$ rvm -v
rvm 1.6.9 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]

$ echo $PATH
/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

Comment: Adam, what `which ruby`, `which rvm` and `rvm -v` commands return?

Comment: What does `rvm current` and `echo $PATH` return?

Comment: Edited answer with updated info as requested

Answer (score 9, accepted):

RVM 1.6.9 is very old now. Did you install it through some package manager? If so, get rid of it and run the following in your bash shell:

`curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`

Then, place `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"` in `~/.profile` OR `~/.bash_profile` OR `~/.bashrc`

You should then be able to run `type rvm | head -n 1` and it should say "rvm is a function".

Then you should be able to install rubies and use one of them. Be sure to use `--default` for that Ruby to remain the default even after you end your terminal session. E.g. `rvm use ruby-1.9.2-p290 --default`

Comment: The other answers helped me to understand some things, but this one solved my RVM woes. Thanks.

Comment: Also, it looks like the latest install script actually updates .bashrc with that line now. So can skip that.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the following line to your `.bash_profile`,

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

as the [installation page for rvm](http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/) says?

Comment: Yes I have added that, except strange thing, when I try `cd $HOME/.rvm` in the terminal, I get: `No such file or directory`

Comment: Usually rvm is located just there, in `$HOME/.rvm`. In this case `which rvm` returns `$HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm`. You probably have rvm installed in a different directory, as the others have noticed.

Answer (score 1):

Like tass suggested you obviously have a different rvm directory then $HOME/.rvm so

```
[[ -s "/usr/share/ruby-rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "/usr/share/ruby-rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

is probably what you would to use instead

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is zombie-old, but in your terminal client's preferences, checking 'run command as login shell' solved it for me.  RVM generally puts that line in your ~/.bash_profile for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, even though it is "zombie-old" ;)