# error while installing ruby 1.9.3 using rvm

Tags: ruby, rvm

I am trying to install ruby using rvm. I get the following error on the below command -

> rvm install 1.9.3
>
> Extracting rubygems-latest-1.8 ...
>
> ERROR: Error running 'gunzip <
>   /usr/share/ruby-rvm/archives/rubygems-latest-1.8.tgz | tar xf - -C
>   /usr/share/ruby-rvm/src', please read
>   /usr/share/ruby-rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/rubygems.extract.log
>
> Installing rubygems for
>   /usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
>
> ERROR: Error running
>   'GEM_PATH="/usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194:/usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global:/usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194:/usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global"
>   GEM_HOME="/usr/share/ruby-rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194"
>   "/usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby"
>   "/usr/share/ruby-rvm/src/rubygems-latest-1.8/setup.rb"', please read
>   /usr/share/ruby-rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/rubygems.install.log

Below is the extract from the log file -

> [2012-07-25 09:29:03] gunzip <
>   /usr/share/ruby-rvm/archives/rubygems-latest-1.8.tgz | tar xf - -C
>   /usr/share/ruby-rvm/src
>
> gzip: stdin: not in gzip format tar: This does not look like a tar
>   archive tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
>   [2012-07-25 09:31:08] gunzip <
>   /usr/share/ruby-rvm/archives/rubygems-latest-1.8.tgz | tar xf - -C
>   /usr/share/ruby-rvm/src
>
> gzip: stdin: not in gzip format tar: This does not look like a tar
>   archive tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

Comment: Per the instructions, what do you see in `/usr/share/ruby-rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/rubygems.extract.log`?

Comment: I have added the details from the log file in the question.

Comment: Could it be the rvm itself? I have v1.6.9 that I installed through apt. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8398479/using-rvm-but-cant-set-current-ruby-version-ubuntu-11-10

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rvm install: ruby installation error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439502/rvm-install-ruby-installation-error); looks like a reinstall of RVM may fix your woes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are using version of RVM broken by packaging for Ubuntu, use this answer to fix:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/9056395/497756